# Faster alternative to doBy/summaryBy

Tags: r, dataframe

I currently use the `summaryBy` command from the `doBy` package to group rows of a data frame by specific functions. This works fine. BUT:

The `doBy` package loads very slow, I think because it imports various other packages. It takes about 3 seconds until `doBy` is loaded. I only need the simple `summaryBy` feature from this package.

Is there a possibility to speed up the loading time of the package or is there a alternative implementation which does not load such a huge package?

Comment: This question belongs on SO as well the other one that was migrated. This one has no statistical content either.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For aggregating large datasets with complicated functions, it's hard to beat the [data.table](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html) package.  For example, here's how you would summarize `mean` and `sd` of `Sepal.Length` for the iris dataset:

```
require(data.table)
dat <- data.table(iris)
dat[,list(mean=mean(Sepal.Length), sd=sd(Sepal.Length)),by=Species]
```

The library loads quickly, it only takes 1 line of code (2 if you count converting your `data.frame` to a `data.table`), and it's very fast.  What more could you want?

Answer (score 6):

You may get more rapid performance by just using the base-R `lapply(split(.))` paradigm with the functions you want.

```
 dat <- structure(list(category = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", 
"B", "C"), class = "factor"), year = c(2000, 2001, 2004, 2005, 
2009, 2010, 2000, 2001, 2004, 2005, 2009, 2010, 2000, 2001, 2004, 
2005, 2009, 2010), incidents = c(7, 4, 4, 2, 3, 1, 6, 3, 5, 2, 
2, 5, 2, 1, 4, 4, 2, 1)), .Names = c("category", "year", "incidents"
), row.names = c(NA, -18L), class = "data.frame")

split(dat, dat$category)
lapply( split(dat[-1], dat$category), summary)
```

Comment: Rapid performance with the `lapply(split(.))` paradigm? Shudder.

Comment: Yes. I can see your amusement Matthew. I was just thinking that it might be _more_ rapid in comparison with doBy.

Answer (score 3):

1) Rather than installing the doBy package, try sourcing `summaryBy.R` and `orderBy.R` from the doBy source package:

```
setwd("doBy/R")
source("summaryBy.R")
source("orderBy.R")

summaryBy(...whatever...)
```

or

2) remove all files in the package except the DESCRIPTION file, the R directory and those two source files (remove all other .R files), remove the Depends: and Imports: lines from the DESCRIPTION file (optionally change the Package: line in the DESCRIPTION to some other name) and then rebuild and install the new stripped down package.  (Another possibility is to leave all the files in the package and just delete the Depends: and Imports: lines from the DESCRIPTION file but that won't load quite as fast as removing nearly everything).